# javascript function to parse multiple forms on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, forms

I have a page that contains two tabs, each tab contains a form. The form gets parsed the same way, only they are being actioned to different URLs/APIs.

I want to use the same function to parse through the forms, instead of repeating the same function, so I was grabbing the hash in the URL to get the tab number and then added that to the jquery target, see code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#tab-container').easytabs();

var tab = '#tab1'; // when index loaded, there is no hash, so I set tab to be #tab1 by default

window.onhashchange= function() {
   tab = window.location.hash;
   console.log(tab);
};


$(tab + ' form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the page from refreshing

    var url = $(this).attr('action')

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $(tab + ' form').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           var result = JSON.parse(data);

           // check to see if there are more than one value in the response. values are separated by commas
           if (result.response.indexOf(",") > -1){ 
                var results = result.response.split(", ");

                // show the results to the left of the form if there are any
                $(tab + ' #results').removeClass('hide');

                for (i=0; i < results.length; i++){
                    $(tab + " #list").append('<li>' + results[i] + '</li>');
                }
           }else{
                results = result;
                $(tab + " #list").append('<li>' + results.response + '</li>');
           }


       }
     });

    return false;
});
```

This does not seem to work, as it will only work for Tab 1. Any other tab will action to the appropriate URL instead of calling that function.

I would like to be able to use the same function for the forms but I'm not sure how to target the specific forms on the change of tabs.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do everything relative to event.target (which will be the form submitted)

Also, don't use IDs for lists and results elements, they should be classes. I can't tell for sure though as I have no HTML markup reference.

http://jsfiddle.net/3HkU6/5/

```
function validateForm(event) {

    // Prevent the page from refreshing
    event.preventDefault();

    var form_el = event.target,
        $form = $(form_el),
        type = $form.attr('method'),
        url = $form.attr('action');

     var $results = $form.siblings('.results'),
         $list = $results.find('.list');


    $.ajax({
       type: type,
       url: url,
       data: $form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data) {
           var results,
               result = JSON.parse(data);

           // check to see if there are more than one value in the response. values are separated by commas
           if (result.response.indexOf(",") > -1){ 

               var results = result.response.split(", ");

                // show the results to the left of the form if there are any
                $results.removeClass('hide');

                for (i=0; i < results.length; i++){
                    $list.append('<li>' + results[i] + '</li>');
                }
           } else {
                results = result;
                $list.append('<li>' + results.response + '</li>');
           }


       }
     });

}


$('form').each(function() {

    this.addEventListener('submit', validateForm);

})
```

HTML

```
<div>
   <form>
   </form>

   <div class="results">
       <ol class="list">
       </ol>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome & exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much! I will mark it as the answer once I make sure it works.

Comment: This works, however the $list.append does not append my results to my ol element with the list class. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, hopefully I can figure it out.

Comment: I have no idea, I can't see the markup. <ul class="list"></ul> does need to be a sibling to the form.

Comment: @Narutkowski
Ahh, so .list is a child of .results. just use $.find() jquery method to select a child element. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I did. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just check ID and react accordingly

```
$('#tab1 form, #tab2 form').submit(){
    if( $(this).is( '#tab1 form') ){
        /* any special form 1 handling */
    }else{

    }     
});
```

As for results just traverse to main tab content element and look within that instance

```
/* defined within submit handler and not inside ajax*/
var $list= $(this).closest('.tabContentClass').find('.listClass');
```

Comment: @charliefl this is pretty much what I was trying to do. I was not familiar with the second part though, so thank you for that!